# Starting another project within main project in a solution for windows phone

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I dont know if this is the right approach or not. But I have created an empty solution in VS2010 and I have added 2 projects to this solution. The first project is a panaroma project, and second one is a normal project (both for windows phone).

For the panaroma project I have added an applciation bar and some items. One of these items is called option and I want to open the second project so the user can set/change some options.

How does one calls another project withing the main project?

```
    private void Options_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Start the project which is called Options
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is just reuse run some code of your second project but in the context of ProjectA (basically as a library), you can just do AddReference in ProjectA to add a reference to project B and use the follwing line to navigate to a page defined in projectB:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/ProjectB;component/SettingsPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

If what you want is to start ProjectB as an external application than in windows phone 8 you can use [Uri association](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). Please note this is available only for windows phone 8 and whichever data are saved in application ProjectB will not be accessible from ProjectA since windows phone application are sandbox.